# How to Convert Void *data to NSdata

Tags: ios

In My app i am using openAl to cut the portion of audio song

```
void *data =  MyGetOpenALAudioDataWithinCUT(fileURL, &size, &format, &freq,m_LowerTimeValue,m_UpperTimeValue);
```

Now i need to convert this void *data  to NSData.

Can any one help me please?

Comment: You have asked 6 questions and accepted answers on 0% of those. You might want to work on that to encourage an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is casting, then

```
NSData *your_data = (NSData *) data;
```

If the void data contains some objects other than NSData you will need to do a more serious conversion

Comment: what is it, what deoes "MyGetOpenALAudioDataWithinCUT" do?

Comment: MyGetOpenALAudioDataWithinCUT will trim the portion of Audio Song

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what `MyGetOpenALAudioDataWithinCUT()` returns. I guess that it's not the case that @Omar Abdelhafith says, and your function simply returns an allocated buffer to the raw binary data, and stores its length in `size`. So, you'll have to use:

```
NSData *nsData = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:size];
```

Comment: it may and it may not be my case, we cant know we could only guess, any guess could be right, but yes i think it is as you said

Comment: ...and all of this confusion's source is the OP, who, again, didn't show any effort to show some related code, or at least the signature of his function...

Comment: after adding that i am getting the NSdata like this is it right or worng this is my log for Nsdata appDelegate.previewdata appDelegate.previewdata <b907b907>                                    can we convert ALuint to NSdata

Comment: That's another question. We'll answer it as soon as you accept one of our answers.